# PHP ftp_connect timeout parameter Not working

Tags: php, ftp, timeout

```
$conn = ftp_connect($server['host'], $server['port'], 5);
ftp_get(@$conn, 'a.txt', 'a.txt', FTP_ASCII);
```

Above code is working 30 minutes for a large a.txt file and never ends despite 5 seconds timeout setting, which according to ftp_connect manual "specifies the timeout in seconds for all subsequent network operations."

Please advice

Comment: I am trying to have a possibility to terminate downloading a file from FTP server after certain period of time and let a script to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to abort the download, when it takes too long, you cannot use `ftp_get` as it is blocking.

---

You have two options. Either use [`ftp_nb_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-get.php):

```
$ret = ftp_nb_get($conn_id, $local_path, $remote_path, FTP_BINARY);

while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA)
{
    if (takes_too_long) break;
    $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
}
```

---

Or [FTP URL protocol wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php):

```
$url = "ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/remote/source/path/file.zip";
$hin = fopen($url, "rb") or die("Cannot open source file");
$hout = fopen("/local/dest/path/file.zip", "wb") or die("Cannot open destination file");

while (!feof($hin))
{
    if (takes_too_long) break;
    $buf = fread($hin, 10240);
    fwrite($hout, $buf);
}
```